# Gitignore: trailing character is any inter

Tags: git, gitignore

In a git repository mainly for LaTeX, I'm writing my `.gitignore`.

I would ignore all `.mtc`, `.mtc1`, `.mtc2`, `.mtc3`... files (with no upper value but it's not the problem). There are others like `.stc`, `.stc1`...;  `.slf`, `.slf1`...

To match them I write

```
*.mtc[0-9]*
```

This doesn't match the "root" `.mtc` file (with no number after).

I prefer to avoid `*.mtc*` which could have side effects.

Is there any other solution than writing it on two lines?

```
*.mtc[0-9]*
*.mtc
```

Comment: Can’t you configure LaTeX to put all those temporary files into a folder?

Comment: `.gitignore` uses wildcard matching, not regex, this gives less flexibility of writing complex one-liners. Your two-line solution is already good enough.

Answer (score 0):

From [`gitignore` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), section "[pattern format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)":

> Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob:
>
> - "`*`" matches anything except "`/`",
> - "`?`" matches any one character except "`/`" and
> - "`[]`" matches one character in a selected range.
>
> See [fnmatch(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) and the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag for a more detailed description.

Based on that pattern specification, you already have the most precise one:

```
*.mtc[0-9]*
*.mtc
```

---

However, as noted by [Code Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209016/gitignore-trailing-character-is-any-inter/51680014?noredirect=1#comment135301814_51680014):

> `*.mtc[0-9]*` matches a single digit and then anything except `/` after the digit.
>
> It does *not* match multiple digits like you might expect coming from regex.

That means this would be enough, but less precise:

```
*.mtc*
*.mtc
```

Or this would work, unless you expect your LaTeX compilation process to create files like `.mtc10`,`.mtc11`, etc.: the provided glob pattern will not cover these files.

```
*.mtc[0-9]
*.mtc
```

Comment: Note that `*.mtc[0-9]*` matches a single digit and then anything except `/` after the digit. It does **not** match multiple digits like you might expect coming from regex.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as long as some alternatives.